# AnythingSlider. How to Swipe right on Last Slide to go to URL?

Tags: jquery, mobile, anythingslider

How would I make "swiperight" on the LAST SLIDE to go to a URL?
(like it does when you click Next on slide 6)

http://nonoisenow.com/slideshow/

JS Code:
http://nonoisenow.com/jscode/swiperight.js

Any advice?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading the documentation properly you can add "swipeleft" and "swiperight" to the list of events that activate the clickForwardArrow and clickBackwardArrow in the `jquery.anythingslider.js` file

This is the original file section for interactivity:

```
// Interactivity
    clickForwardArrow   : "click",         // Event used to activate forward arrow functionality (e.g. add jQuery mobile's "swiperight")
    clickBackArrow      : "click",         // Event used to activate back arrow functionality (e.g. add jQuery mobile's "swipeleft")
    clickControls       : "click focusin", // Events used to activate navigation control functionality
    clickSlideshow      : "click",         // Event used to activate slideshow play/stop button
    allowRapidChange    : false,           // If true, allow rapid changing of the active pane, instead of ignoring activity during animation
```

This how it should look after adding the events (I think):

```
// Interactivity
    clickForwardArrow   : "click swiperight",         // Event used to activate forward arrow functionality (e.g. add jQuery mobile's "swiperight")
    clickBackArrow      : "click swipeleft",         // Event used to activate back arrow functionality (e.g. add jQuery mobile's "swipeleft")
    clickControls       : "click focusin", // Events used to activate navigation control functionality
    clickSlideshow      : "click",         // Event used to activate slideshow play/stop button
    allowRapidChange    : false,           // If true, allow rapid changing of the active pane, instead of ignoring activity during animation
```

Comment: I've tried doing that and couldn't get it to work… I'm going to paste my code on the thread

Comment: I noticed in the comment in that code, it says 'jQuery mobile' , perhaps it needs a jquery mobile js file to be ref'd in your page too?

Comment: but also you added it to `swiperight.js` rather than `jquery.anythingslider.js` ? or did I miss something

Comment: I tried jquery mobile like it suggested in the comments. it didn't work. it caused other issues also. i think i figure out a work around for now… just added another slide and then added an event to that slide to go to a page. http://nonoisenow.com/slideshow/

Comment: just doesn't look good if you hit the back button on the browser. that will be my next challenge to solve. lol

Answer (score 0):

Modify the swipe code to check if the swipe is occurring on the last page, if it is, then go to the desired URL ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/8174/))

```
if (newx < x) {
    if (slider.currentPage < slider.pages) {
        slider.goForward(); 
    } else if (slider.currentPage === slider.pages) {
        // swipe while on the last page will go to google
        // doesn't work in this demo because of iframes
        window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
    }
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
/******************************************
  Swipe Demo - without using jQuery Mobile
 ******************************************/

$('#slider').anythingSlider({

    // Callback when the plugin finished initializing
    onInitialized: function(e, slider) {

        var time = 1000, // allow movement if < 1000 ms (1 sec)
            range = 50,  // swipe movement of 50 pixels triggers the slider
            x = 0, t = 0, touch = "ontouchend" in document,
            st = (touch) ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown',
            mv = (touch) ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',
            en = (touch) ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';

        $('<div class="swipe-overlay"></div>')
            .appendTo(slider.$window)
            .bind(st, function(e){
                // prevent image drag (Firefox)
                e.preventDefault();
                t = (new Date()).getTime();
                x = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX; 
            })
            .bind(en, function(e){
                t = 0; x = 0;
            })
            .bind(mv, function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var newx = e.originalEvent.touches ? e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX : e.pageX,
                r = (x === 0) ? 0 : Math.abs(newx - x),
                // allow if movement < 1 sec
                ct = (new Date()).getTime();
                if (t !== 0 && ct - t < time && r > range) {
                    if (newx < x) {
                        if (slider.currentPage < slider.pages) {
                            slider.goForward(); 
                        } else if (slider.currentPage === slider.pages) {
                            // swipe while on the last page will go to google
                            // doesn't work in this demo because of iframes
                            window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
                        }
                    }
                    if (newx > x) { slider.goBack(); }
                    t = 0; x = 0;
                }
            });

    }

});
```